# Is there a way on how to integrate TortoiseSVN with FileZilla?

Tags: version-control, centos, tortoisesvn, filezilla

I am using Tortoise1.6, SubversionEdge for SVN CMS and FileZilla3 (Test Server has CentOS as Server).
**Let's assume the scenario:**
- Test Server exists - *here, developers have direct access; used for user testing*
- There are 3 members in a team
- 2 of the members are developing on their local machine using TortoiseSVN
- But 1 wants to develop directly on the Test Server
--> The issue on developing directly on the Test Server are:
     1.) No TortoiseSVN installed
     2.) Even if SVN exist in TestServer, command scripts are tedious since it is running on CentOS (no GUI)
This issue can be resolved with team management, but the challenging part in here is how to address the technical issue (as this is maybe a future need).

**QUESTION**
So, my question is - is there a way to integrate TortoiseSVN on FileZilla?
Or a way that after committing changes on the working copy, files in the Test Server are also updated?
If you were on my situation, how would you address such issue aside from just team mgt/agreement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tortoisesvn is an explorer shell-extension. It doesn't know how to access Filezilla's functions to access the files on the ftp server.

What you can do is using a smb-share over a vpn-network. TortoiseSVN ist then able to directly see the files and display them correctly in explorer - although this solution may be quite slow depending on your network-connection.

However, what I usually do is developing locally, connect via ssh to the server and then use the svn cmd-line utility to do updates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply/answers. I will be researching on "smb-share" as you mentioned.
Well, I am also considering... the TestServer will always listen to SVN, and sync the project/files that needs update.
If ever you can, can you provide me links about "smb-share". Or if you also have ideas on TestServer-SVN synching? Though I will also be doing my research. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Often times, it is really needed that the working copy should be in TestServer since their are codes/lines (ie., links, database config, etc.) that depends on the server environment. So, right now, I am resorting to synching SVN with the TestServer. Any ideas/help would be appreciated.

Comment: SMB is a microsoft networking protocol: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Server_Message_Block When you want to access files on your CentOS server you will need a program called "Samba" which should somehow be available for CentOS. But this is more a sysadmin- than a programmer question. Ask them onhttp://serverfault.com/ The people there will probably know better how to help you.